# How to implement a role system based on points akin to stackoverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm currently building an application in rails3 where you are given points for doing various things and I'd like to implement a system, like stackoverflow, where you get more admin rights as you get more points.

So what would be the best way to implement such a system in rails?  I'd like to keep it from getting too complex.  Would you just have a ton of roles and keep adding an removing them from users?  Or should I just compare how many points a user has to how many they need to do something.  The nice thing about the second options though is I could generate an error message if they try to do something with out enough points.

I was thinking of using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for this but i'm open to suggestions.  I just found [CanTango](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango) which seems interesting.  It just [extends CanCan](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango/wiki/CanCan-vs-CanTango).

Answer (score 0):

Do as you first suggested. That lets you decouple roles from points, so you can more easily adjust the matchups later if needed.

Also, there are potential performance benefits, because you are only looking up what roles a user has. By linking based on points, you may run into performance issues, depending on how you store the earned / deducted points.